# Remove duplicate based on condition awk/bash

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicates from a dataset which has 3 columns

```
A       0   3238
B       0   3367
C       0   3130
D       1   3130
```

I need to remove lines which contain duplicate values in the third column, but preferentially keeping those with the value '1' in the second column. I know how to remove duplicates using awk, but I can't work out how to add in the conditional statment.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this line a try:

```
awk '{if($3 in a)a[$3]=$2==1?$0:a[$3];else a[$3]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

Comment: +1 for neat way to solve it. I did not at first realize that `$2==1?$0:a[$3]` is evaluated before `=` wish was a bit confusing. I guess `a[$3]=($2==1?$0:a[$3])` would work as well.

Comment: @Qben yes it does. and with brackets it would be easier to read.

Comment: The syntax without brackets is non-portable, e.g. it would fail syntactically on MacOS awks (or so I hear...).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sort -k2nr file | awk '!seen[$3]++'
D       1   3130
A       0   3238
B       0   3367
```

Comment: Interesting bits of `awk`. Can you please explain the `!seen[$3]++` part ?

Comment: It's the common awk idiom to only output the first value in a series of potential duplicates. Every time a value is used as an index in the array the array's entry for that value is post-incremented, so the first time a value is seen it's array entry is zero so the `!` operator makes the overall result true. After that first time though the array entry is non-zero so the `!` makes the result false. It's like `uniq` but doesn't require the values to be sorted and let's you operate on fields rather than the whole input line/record.